# Как отключить свайп на slick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

обрый день, есть слайдер, ( управление через стрелки и доты) однако есть же возможность и свайпа на мобильниках. Как отключить данную возможость, сильно мешает ибо там слайдер в слайдере и конфликтует ( бывает не тот слайд перемешяет :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается такое есть уже :D

```
swipe: false
```